# Marklogic Admin UI and Query console not accessible

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

HI I am not able to access Marklogic admin UI port(8001) or query console(8000) from browser, it gives the error from browser "This site can’t be reached".

when i checked ErrorLog.txt there is an error "Error: AppRequestTask::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Security-4-replica-1 not mounted: disconnected".

I tried with restarting Marklogic server but no luck still admin UI (8001) and query console(8000) not accessible.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: Are there any hosts down? Based upon the naming convention, a replica forest being down shouldn't be an issue - unless the primary Security-4 forest is also offline. You need either the primary or the replica forest to be online and available. If Security DB is offline, then you will have availability issues. By the way, you should only have one primary Security forest (and HA replica): https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/admin-guide/en/databases/understanding-databases.html

Comment: Thank your for your response @Mads Hansen, i checked all the host are up, i tried by restarting by all three node but still i am not able to access PORT 8001 and 8000

Comment: @Mads Hansen one more thing, if  If Security DB is offline then how can i resolve this if i am not able to access admin UI (8001)

Comment: BTW i checked the log and found that "2023-12-12 23:18:13.669 Info: Mounted forest Security remotely on XXXb02"

Comment: Where is the location of Security-4-replica-1 forest, that machine is up?

Comment: @NavinRawat All node are UP, and "ecurity-4-replica-1 forest" is replica and the main security forest getting mount as i have mentioned above, also i checked with infrastructure team about PORT 8001 if it is blocking, but it is not blocked

Comment: If the servers are up, then what about communications and hostname resolution? Are there any indications of quorum issues or a lot of XDQP server/client restarts?

Comment: @MadsHansen I had checked ErrorLog.txt nothing found apart from ""Error: AppRequestTask::run: XDMP-FORESTMNT: Forest Security-4-replica-1" , also i checked that the security forest and "Security-4" forest getting mounted , also i checked Access_log8001, there is no any error. about "quorum"  this is from log "Detected quorum (3 online, 0 suspect, 0 offline)"